# Only pipe output if at least n lines

Tags: grep, pipe, tail, head

I often want to grep output from processes that include a few header lines. But if grep would remove all actual content lines, I don't want to display the header lines. For this to work I would need a command similar to `tail` but instead of only returning n lines, it would return *all* lines but only if there are at least n lines (the header).

A colleague wrote a small Python tool to do this but it needs installation on all machines where I need to do this.

Is there a short command line that can achieve this effect using a standard tool (maybe awk?) ?

Answer (score 4):

You could save the first `n` lines in an awk array, and write them out when (and if) you see line `n + 1`, which is when you discover you have at least one data line.

```
Awk_N='
FNR <= N { X[FNR] = $0; next; }
FNR == N + 1 {
    for (j = 1; j in X; ++j) print X[j];
    delete X;
}
{ print; }
'

awk -v N=7 "${Awk_N}"
```

I made the `7` a shell-space variable so it can be substituted without editing the Awk part.

The Awk part is predeclared as a single-quoted multiline shell string variable to declutter your pipeline.

You might also consider whether you can fold the grep logic into the `awk` at the same time.

Somewhat briefer version, which stores all the lines.

```
awk '{ X[NR] = $0 } END { if (NR > 3) for (j = 1; j in X; ++j) print X[j] }'
```

This minimises character count (at the expense of readability).

```
awk '{X[NR]=$0}END{if(NR>3)for(j=1;j in X;++j)print X[j]}'
```

Comment: Hmm, nice try but that's still about half as long as the Python script I have now.

Comment: I'm guessing you meant it is twice as long as the Python. It could be 3 lines easily, or a nasty one-liner, but sometimes terse is worse.

Comment: No, I did mean that the verbose Python version I have is about twice as long. I was hoping for somehing like 15-20 characters. Is the whitespace important in awk?

Comment: Unusual for Awk to be more compact than Python. In Awk, you can remove most spaces between tokens, but not those between text: jinX and printX break it. I'm not clear why number of characters matters: if you are typing this every time you need it, you should script it (in the readable form), and probably parameterize the `3` to make it useful in other contexts.

Comment: I would add that storing *all* the lines (although a shorter command) has two issues: (a) For a huge file, it will use a lot of memory. (b) It disrupts the even flow through a pipeline, so (e.g.) a following `tail` command would only get its first data when the whole input has been processed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `sed` one-liner (assuming you wanted to print all if there are at least 4 lines, i.e. `n=4`) :

```
cmd | sed -e '4,$!{H;1h;d;}' -e '4H;4x'
```

so, if you want to use variables

```
cmd | sed -e "${n}"',$!{H;1h;d;}' -e "${n}H;${n}x"
```

What this does is save the first `n-1` lines in the `H`old buffer and `d`eletes them from pattern space so nothing gets printed... unless `sed` receives at least one more line - the `n`th one, and adds it to the `H`old space and then it e`x`changes buffers so now the pattern space contains lines `1` to `n`. The rest is just a matter of auto-printing.
On some non-GNU setups you might need to write it like this (let's say `n=21` this time):

```
cmd | sed '21,$!{
H;1h;d
}
21H;21x'
```

Answer (score 1):

If header is 7 lines long, we can remove it if input length is <= 7.
Using Perl or (gnu)sed:

```
cmd... | perl -0pe 's/^(.*\n){,7}$//'
cmd... | sed   -zE 's/^(.*\n){,7}$//m'
```

(avoid doing this with gigabytes inputs)

Comment: That's excellent! Best answer yet. I'll leave it open for a few days before accepting. But I wonder if `sed` can do it with a similarly concise regex syntax?

Comment: @Colin'tHart , yes: with gnugrep (the one normaly presente in linux and many others) you can `cmd... |  sed -zE 's/^(.*\n){,7}$//m' `

Comment: @Colin'tHart you asked for a solution using a standard tool but neither the perl script nor the sed script in this answer would work with POSIX standard tools yet you say this is the best answer. So, please edit your question to explain what you mean by "standard" and also explain your criteria for a "best" answer (it seems like to you briefest might be best rather than most portable, efficient, clear, robust, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind to run your search twice you can do something like that:

```
N=18; alias search='grep -R manual /usr/share/man/'

[ $(search | wc -l) -ge $N ] && search
```

Comment: No, I don't want to run the search twice. It can be expensive, for example a database query, or data retrieved over the network. Yes, I know I can adjust my database queries, but the output will be two rows for the column header and then `(0 rows)`. If I use cron for example, it will generate an email if there's output. If I can pipe it through a simple command that will only output if there are more than 3 lines, I only get the cron email if there's actual data from the query.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it using `tee` and `wc`:

```
cmd | tee x | [ `wc -l <&0` -gt 3 ] && cat x && rm x
```

In this case it's outputting the whole output if it has more than 3 lines.

NB1 Counting the number of lines in the whole file is overkill when you only need to know if there are more than 3.

NB2 Further reducing performance, this writes a temporary file. Using `mkfifo` would make it in memory as I understand it, but then the command would be longer.

Comment: You may as well just write ```cmd > x && [ `wc -l <x` -gt 3 ] && cat x && rm x```, the `tee`  and `<&0` are adding no value. You should also copy/paste your scripts into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it tells you about such as using backticks instead of `$(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to print the input if it contains 3 or more lines then this will do that using any awk in any shell on every Unix box and without reading all of the input into memory as some of the other answers (e.g. using `perl -0` or `sed -z`) would do:

```
awk 'NR<3{h=h $0 ORS; next} {print h $0; h=""}'
```

e.g.:

```
$ seq 2 | awk 'NR<3{h=h $0 ORS; next} {print h $0; h=""}'
$

$ seq 4 | awk 'NR<3{h=h $0 ORS; next} {print h $0; h=""}'
1
2
3
4
$
```